# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined during Testing React with Axios

Tags: reactjs, testing, axios, jestjs, spy

***Header.js***

```
const formSubmitHandle = () => {
   if (string !== "") {
       httpService.fetchData(var1, var2).then((res) => {
           //stuff to do...
       });
   } else {
      console.log("Type something to search");
   }
};
```

***HttpService.js***

```
const HttpService = {

     fetchData(var1,var2) {
        const url = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/" + some code..

        return axios.get(url);
    },
};
```

**Testing.js (the spying function )**

```
  const apiFunc = jest
      .spyOn(HttpService, "fetchData")
      .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
          return Promise.resolve({
              json: () => Promise.resolve(MockResponseData),
         });
      });
```

**And the error I'm getting**

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

  26 |   const formSubmitHandle = () => {
  27 |     if (keypress !== "") {
> 28 |       httpService.fetchData(var1, var2).then((res) => {
     |       ^
```

**The function call is returned** and works properly in the actual app, so why is it getting undefined?

> --> return axios.get(url);

Comment: What does your test look like?